# Execute some code if element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I want to execute some code if this element exists `<div id="element">Some text</div>` using jquery.

my code until now:

```
setInterval(function(){check()}, 100);

function check() {

   var count = document.getElementById("count");
   if(document.getElementById("element") && count.value != 1) {
      //some code
      count.value = 1;
   }

}
```

It works, but I think this is a very bad way to reach my target.
I want an easier solution, but I didn't find.

Comment: you can have a look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) - if it is not supported then use the way you have now

Comment: You're doing the right thing. It doesn't feel right, but it is.

Comment: if you want to use jQuery you can look at the function [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: The current code seems fine to me, except I would move the `getElementById("count")` inside the if since you don't use `count` outside the if. And you can simplify the `setInterval` part to `setInterval(check, 100);`.

Comment: Other way would be to use CSS3 transition event but better would be you explain what can add or not this specific element into the DOM. If it's an ajax request, then use relevant methods as success callback to check it

Answer (score 0):

Your way is the most reliable, because it cannot fail.

However, you may wish to try listening for `change` events on the `count` element, and reset the value if your `element` exists. This will mean your verification code only runs when a change is made to the value.

Comment: _"because it cannot fail"_ - Except that it'll give an error if the `count` element doesn't exist.

Comment: @nnnnnn Doesn't matter, because in such a case there is nothing to do anyway, and since it's asynchronous code (run independently in an `interval`), it doesn't block further code from running. The lack of a counter *is* an error condition, so it is correct to throw an error here.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to do this initially?

hjow about you do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(#element)) { do something };
});
```

EDIT:

after 10 seconds of search:

```
$("#someDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
```

Comment: The question is clearly trying to monitor a value and lock it when a given element exists. Your answer doesn't help...

Comment: then try to read through the jquery docs and find a handler that does what you want or just proceed how you do it... like the way you appreciate the approach of helping

Comment: i have edited my comment... now you can find a selector like $(body) to register the handler on the DOMsubtreeModified event... this will recognize when something happend to the subtree of your DOM - pretty straight forward... and no need to do the queuespam

Comment: Hmm... usually with `DOMsubtreeModified` you want to register the handler as far down as you can, and almost never on the `body`.

Comment: Yes then do that! I dont know where you want to "listen" for changes - i think you know best! !!! :D:D:D:D

Answer (score 0):

You can listen DOM events (when an element is inserted or modified) and check your condition only at this time, not every time interval.

If you need some information about DOM events you can take a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#HTML_events (mutation events)

Comment: But which browsers support the DOM events? The mutation events on that Wikipedia page are deprecated now...

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is about using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) with a fallback mechanism like

```js
jQuery(function() {

  if (window.MutationObserver) {
    var target = document.querySelector('#myparent');

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        [].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(el, i) {
          if (el.id == 'element') {
            check();
            //if you don't want to listen any more remove the listener
            //observer.disconnect();
          }
        })
      });
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    var config = {
      childList: true
    };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target, config);

  } else {
    setInterval(function() {
      if (document.getElementById("element")) {
        check();
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  function check() {
    var count = document.getElementById("count");
    if (count.value != 1) {
      //some code
      count.value = 1;
    }
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  $('#myparent').append('<div id="element">Some text</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add</button>
<input id="count" />
<div id="myparent"></div>
```

*Note: The solution assumes you have a static parent element for the dynamic element(like the `myparent` element in the above example)*